# jstl сравнение двух строк(переменные)

Tags: java, java-ee, jstl

По какой-то причине результат сравнения всегда false. 
Вот код:

```
<c:forEach var="elem" items="${sessionScope.users}">
  <c:if test="${elem eq user}">
     Do smt
  </c:if>
  <c:if test="${elem ne user}">
    do other
  </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Конкретно не могу сравнить 2 строковые переменные. Результат всегда **false**

```
test="${elem eq user}"
```

user присутствует в области видимости.
что делаю не так?

Answer (score -1):

Нашел ответ — явно вызвать .toString()

```
${elem.toString() eq user.toString()}
```